# Is "more of such examples" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, determiners

Let us assume that in a text we bring an example.
And we want to bring more similar examples.
Is this statement grammatically correct?

> There are more of such examples

How about the following:

> There are more such examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is slightly more idiomatic in American English, but both are comprehensible and acceptable despite being somewhat verbose. Purely as a matter of style, I suggest

> Similar examples include ...